# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation elemMatch

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using spring data whith mongodb and I have a c_user collection in MongoDB as below:

```
db.c_user.find().pretty();

{
        "_id" : "user-1",
        "journeys" : [
            {
                "fromStation" : "A",
                "toStation" : "B"
            },
            {
                "fromStation" : "B",
                "toStation" : "C"
            },
            {
                "fromStation" : "A",
                "toStation" : "D"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "user-2",   
        "journeys" : [
            {
                "fromStation" : "A",
                "toStation" : "B"
            },
            {
                "fromStation" : "B",
                "toStation" : "C"
            },
            {
                "fromStation" : "D",
                "toStation" : "E"
            }
        ]
    }
```

What I want is to get a list of c_user documents matching 'journeys.fromStation' == "A". So if you run the following query in mongo shell:

```
db.c_user.runCommand({ 
   "aggregate" : "c_user" , 
   "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "journeys.fromStation" : "A"}} , 
                  { "$unwind": "$journeys"} , 
                  { "$match" : { "journeys.fromStation" : "A"}}
                ]
});
```

I get list of c_user docs back which is what I expect:

```
{
    "_id" : "user-1",
    "journeys" : [
        {
            "fromStation" : "A",
            "toStation" : "B"
        },
        {
            "fromStation" : "A",
            "toStation" : "D"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "user-2",   
    "journeys" : [
        {
            "fromStation" : "A",
            "toStation" : "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Now I need to do this with spring data mongo aggregation:

```
TypedAggregation<CUser> aggregation = newAggregation(CUser.class,
                match(where("journeys.fromStation").is("A")),
                unwind("journeys"),
                match(where("journeys.fromStation").is("A")));

        AggregationResults<CUser> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, CUser.class);

        return results.getMappedResults();
```

when this is executed, I get the this error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

Obviously its a List.class which cannot be instantiated. And it seems that the object that is returned is BasicDbLIst.

Anyway, so how do I get same result as mongo shell? i.e. as a `List<CUser>`

Any help appreciated...

Regards
GM

Comment: Is it `"favJourneys.fromStation"` or `"journeys.fromStation"`?

Comment: sorry its should have been "journeys.fromStation".

Comment: Any help from SPRING-DATA team would be appreciated.

Comment: Which release version are you using?

Comment: @chridam - I am using spring-boot v 1.2.3.RELEASE and mongo  v2.6.7

Comment: is this Solved? I am facing the same issue. have you solved it?